# 3D Surface Streaming in Plotly

Tags: python, plot, 3d, plotly, surface

I am trying to generate a 3D surface using Plotly's streaming API and I receive no errors in the actual Python code however I get the "Oops! An error occured while loading this plot's data" on Plotly. Here is my code:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.tools as tls
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from random import uniform
import pandas as pd
import time

tls.set_credentials_file(username='', api_key='')

stream_id = tls.get_credentials_file()['stream_ids']
token = stream_id[-1]

stream_id = dict(token=token)

z = []

surface = go.Surface(z=z, stream=stream_id)
data = [surface]
layout = go.Layout(
     title='Test',
     autosize=False,
     width=500,
     height=500,
     margin=dict(
         l=65,
         r=50,
         b=65,
         t=90
     )
 )
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plot_url = py.iplot(fig, filename='elevations-3d-surface', auto_open=True)

s = py.Stream(stream_id=token)
s.open()

matrices = []
for p in range(5):
    matrix = []
    for x in range(25):
        row = []
        for y in range(25):
            row.append(uniform(25, 100))
        matrix.append(row)
    test = pd.DataFrame(matrix)
    print(test)
    matrices.append(matrix)
print(pd.DataFrame(matrices[1]))

i = 0
while True:
    step = 3
    z = matrices[i]
    s.write(go.Surface(z=z))
    time.sleep(step)
    i += 1
    if i == len(matrices):
        i = 0
    print(i)
    # print(pd.DataFrame(z))
s.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it work, here is my final code:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.tools as tls
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
from random import uniform
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

tls.set_credentials_file(username='', api_key='')

stream_id = tls.get_credentials_file()['stream_ids']
token = stream_id[-1]

stream_id = dict(token=token)

z_init = np.zeros(100).reshape((10, 10))
z = z_init

surface = go.Surface(z=z, stream=stream_id)
data = [surface]
layout = go.Layout(
     title='Test',
     autosize=False,
     width=500,
     height=500,
     margin=dict(
         l=65,
         r=50,
         b=65,
         t=90
     )
 )
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plot_url = py.iplot(fig, filename='', auto_open=True)

s = py.Stream(stream_id=token)
s.open()

arr_width = 25
arr_length = 25

matrices = []
for p in range(100):
    matrix = []
    for x in range(arr_width):
        row = []
        for y in range(arr_length):
            row.append(uniform(-1, 1))
        matrix.append(row)
    matrices.append(matrix)

##################################################################

# given 2 arrays arr1, arr2, number of steps between arrays, and order of interpolation
# numpoints = 10
# order = 2
# arr1 = matrices[1]
# arr2 = matrices[2]


def interp(arr1, arr2, numpoints, order):

    # rejoin arr1, arr2 into a single array of shape (2, 10, 10)
    arr = np.r_['0, 3', arr1, arr2]

    # define the grid coordinates where you want to interpolate
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(arr_width), np.arange(arr_length))

    k = 0
    interp_arr_vec = []
    while k <= 1:
        coordinates = np.ones((arr_width, arr_length))*k, X, Y
        # given arr interpolate at coordinates
        interp_arr = ndimage.map_coordinates(arr, coordinates, order=order).T
        interp_arr_vec.append(interp_arr)

        step = 1 / numpoints
        k += step

    return interp_arr_vec

##################################################################

sleep_time = .1

i = 0
while True:

    between_test = interp(matrices[i], matrices[i+1], 200, 3)

    r = 0
    for r in range(len(between_test)):
        s.write(go.Surface(z=between_test[r]))
        time.sleep(sleep_time)

    i += 1
    print('i = ', i)
    time.sleep(3)

    if i == len(matrices):
        i = 0

s.close()
```

Comment: can this be achieved in javascript as well ??

Comment: I can't imagine that support for Python would precede that of JS. In fact I believe the Python API depends on the JS. If your asking __how__ to do it in JS then you might share some code

Comment: i have a bluetooth serial communications device which sends z axis data through bluetooth at below 300ms per stream of data ,how can i use surface plot feature of plotly in a javasciprt web view based android app the streams data to the javascript via the javascript interface and refreshes the graph's data without loosing it's camera  position

Comment: i also dont understand it's streaming api properly ... why do we need to use an api key for streaming data over bluetooth , or is that streaming api not for bluetooth purpose ?

Comment: Streaming doesn't pertain to trasmittence of data through a protocol per se. It just means that the data is updated based on time.

Comment: right it did seem something like that to me too , so then why do we need to make an api key to stream it over python .. also the only documentation i found in js is at this link https://plot.ly/javascript/streaming/ and they are mostly covering a function called extendTraces in but in my case i want to plot a 3d surface and , the entire data per stream can change , is there any plotly api or function that just updates data without effecting camera pos, i m currently using a function called plotly.react to redraw everytime after 300 ms , is there any better you can help me with ??

Comment: Post a link to your code - I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to say i.e. I think you are misunderstanding how the stream works. By api key do you mean the stream token? What do you mean by "entire data per stream can change"? The "stream" is flow of local data to plot.ly rendering service based on specified time parameters. How is plotly affecting your camera pos? What are you "redraw"ing?

Comment: Ohhhh, the api key for plotly is needed if you are plotting "online" which happens by default so to speak. In python you can usually run services in offline mode however I believe that the stream service requires that you plot online thus you need a plotly api key. I'll see if I can get an example up and running later - just remind me. Also, post a separate question on StackOverflow and link it in comment here and I will answer it there if someone doesn't beat me to it